# How to send one or the other attribute in the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form for which I am using checkboxes (Not using radio buttons for my purpose). The problem I run into is when I submit a form, I get an error saying `params is missing or value is empty:checkup`. I am trying to use hidden filed but get the same error. HOw to have an option of sending only one if selected?

```
   def checkup_params
    params.require(:checkup).permit(:eye, :heart)
   end
```

my form:

```
<%= form_for(@checkup) do |f| %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag "checkup[eye]", nil %>
 <%= check_box_tag :eye, "eye" %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag "checkup[heart]", nil %>     
 <%= check_box_tag :heart, "heart" %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't think you properly understand your error. If you do `params.require(:checkup)`, then the params *must* contain the `checkup` key. I don't really understand your question, though.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest reading this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects

Most specifically section 2.2. You really shouldn't be using tag helpers here.